# Feature 'logo/labels' on cases of self made devices

Tags: bluetooth, device, markings, generic, semiconductor-process-technology

Not really an electronics question however has something to do with the tech you have used for your own projects. For example, on any consumer device with USB support, Bluetooth, HDMI 2.x etc there is a tech feature logo/label present that indicate the tech supported/involved. Of course you can use a marker or something similar however is there a way to do this more neat and professionally?

I have searched on many different keywords and only found some (car-) brands, car features - 'turbo' and such, custom logo's, NFC stickers etc however no 'default' consumer tech/feature label stuff. Does it exists and if not, how did you do this? I think this a very common thing to label the features the device support. Also when you extend an existing device with a new feature, like I do, for example adding Bluetooth. It is nice when the added feature logo is present on the case because normally you don't expect this.

Are there any generic/default options at this field?

Comment: it may be illegal for you to use some of the logos without paying a royalty

Answer (score 2):

> For example, on any consumer device…

> Of course you can use a marker

**No.**

Nobody can use these logos without some sort of conditions; they typically are registered designs, and usage is usually only granted after paying a royalty (among others, HDMI! That's why a lot of expensive measurement equipment has displayport instead of HDMI: Nobody wants to attach a TV screen to it, and DP is royalty-free) and/or demonstration of technical compatibility (WiFi, Bluetooth,…).

You (and manufacturers of consumer electronics) can't just go and use some logo because you want to. Doing it regardless leaves you open to legal injunctions, or your goods being seized on entry to the country where you want to sell them.

> Are there any generic/default options at this field?

Printing custom stickers in any count that is relevant to a consumer device is essentially as expensive as buying "standardized" stickers, so I doubt that. It's, in the end, advertisement, and you'd want that to be well-aligned with product design.

Comment: USB has a strict requirements to use logo also: https://www.usb.org/logo-license
It clearly states that company needs to have an assigned vendor ID which costs $5000/year only, also the device has to pass compliance test.
Very similar conditions listed for Bluetooth: https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/marketing-branding/
So @Codebeat, better not putting those on your device even for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact really strange because when you purchased a module with tech and use it in your project, no fee is payed already to use the label? Weird. everything is about money these days. Anyway I am not talking about selling devices, just one (or a proto-type), just for the nice finish and not only a box with knobs without any indication what it exactly will do. The logo's presents a double function, users recognize it and you can see what kind of tech is on the inside. Especially when the device is extended with some functionality you normally don't expect.... (see next)

Comment: ....... Okay, I will print my own, I don't care about legal or not like I explained above already. What do you use to label knobs and buttons instead? Paper? Laser print on transparent sheet? How to print white labels? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, no problem if it's a device you're not selling or putting a photograph of on an advert or something. But you asked based on consumer products having these logos, and yes, for some of them money went from A to B and/or testing had to be done. How's that surprising? Ever tried to use the logo of the hotdog stand down the street on your café without actually selling their hotdogs? Printing labels: it depends on your equipment and use case. You can order stickers, write with felt-tip markers on labels, emboss, whatever. That's really not much of an electrical engineering question, is it?